# Chemical Formulae in fraction

Tags: fractions, chemistry

I was trying to write an equation for equilibrium constant `K`, but I cannot put `Fe(SCN)^2` in the fraction for some reasons. This is what my code was.

```
K=\frac{\ce{[Fe(SCN)^2+]}}{\ce{[Fe^3+][SCN^-]}}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX. community. What is the full compilable code starting from \documentclass, please?

Comment: Did you remember to place the expression shown above in math mode? For sure, if I do that (and remember to load the `mhchem` package in the preamble), I experience no problem typesetting the fraction.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

the \ce command can be used in math mode

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
    \[
    K=\frac{\ce{[Fe(SCN)^2+]}}{\ce{[Fe^3+][SCN^-]}}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP's issue is, quite likely, that they just forgot to place the formula that contains `\frac` into either inline or display math mode.

Comment: As a chemist I find the way the charges are presented in the formulas rather odd. The signs are relatively large. I made the equilibrium equation using `chemmacros` and obtained the same result. Is this something related to `ams` and can it be circumvented?

Comment: @alchemist --  I think AMS "forces" this. If you write \ce{[Fe(SCN)^{\tiny 2+}]} in math mode, nothing changes, but if you write it outside of math mode, \tiny takes effect and the font gets smaller.  But the size of the "+" sign shown in the image is the default size in mhchem